# linear algebra- inverse function

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\ T:\Bbb R^3\rightarrow \Bbb R^3$ be the linear tranformation defined by
$\ T(a,b,c)=(2a-b,a+b+c,-a+c)$,

Find a basis for the Range (T).

I already solved the standard matrix $\ A=
$$ \left[    
  \begin{matrix}
    2 & -1 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    -1 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right] $$
$ and the inverse of $A$, $ A^-1=
$$ \left[    
  \begin{matrix}
    1/4 & 1/4 & -1/4 \\
    -1/2 & 1/2 & -1/2 \\
    1/4 & 1/4 & 3/4 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right] $$
$ (both of them were solved correctly).

Then use the matrix found above to find the rule of assignment for $T ^-1$, that is, find $T^-1 (x)$

Answer (score 1):

$$T^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
    1/4 & 1/4 & -1/4 \\
    -1/2 & 1/2 & -1/2 \\
    1/4 & 1/4 & 3/4 \\
    \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\frac14\begin{pmatrix}x+y-z\\-2x+2y-2z\\x+y+3z\end{pmatrix}$$

Of course, the above is wrt the usual standard basis, as the one you used to find $\;A\;$ .

Comment: thanks, I think you might have a typo, the second row should be $-2x+2y-2z$. But indeed, I wrote the answer like that, using a, b, c instead of x, y, z and I did not factorize 1/4 out either @DonAntonio

Comment: @A.H Of course you're right. Corrected, and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since $T$ is invertible, its range is $\Bbb R^3$. So, you may just take the standard basis of $\Bbb R^3$.